# How can I know how much files I can open without stuck the computer

Tags: c#, file, memory

I have a data grid view with links to xml files and I give the user option to open them in IE.
My Question is how can I know how much files the computer can open without crash\stuck (to show warning message box).
In additional, how can I know how much sleep time I need?

My code:

```
if (dg_autoTestStatus.SelectedRows.Count >= MaxFilesCanOpen(/* How to implement this function */))
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Your computer should crash from opening too much files at same time.\n"
                    + "Are you want to continue ?", "Warning",
                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if (dr == DialogResult.No) return;
}

string pathXMLfile = "";
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvItem in dg_autoTestStatus.SelectedRows)
{
    pathXMLfile += "\\" + dg_logs.Rows[dgvItem.Index].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
    pathXMLfile += "\\" + dg_logs.Rows[dgvItem.Index].Cells[7].FormattedValue.ToString();
    openXMLfile(pathXMLfile);
    Thread.Sleep(500); // how can I know how much sleep I need ?!?
}
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe I'm wrong my perception, but If you have a directory with 300 word files (doc files), now you select all of them and press enter. What should be?
And I use sleep becuase without else any xml opening in new window and not in new tab.

Comment: Before attempting to answer your question, I have the following enquiries: 1) What are you trying to achieve? 2) Why do you think you need Thread.Sleep?

Comment: easy, 0 sleep time, dont use it

Comment: @Tarik: I try to supply safety for the user. for example, if the user select all data grid view (about 700 rows) and chose to open the XML files it's can take a lot of time, or even stuck the computer and just reboot will "help" him - it's I want to prevent. About the sleep, I realy don't know if I need it..

Comment: Would it be practical for the user - from a usage point of view - to open 50 files in one shot as a matter of example? Put yourself in the shoes of a user, would it make sense to you, would it be reasonable? If you can answer this question and the number of files is low enough then just hardcode a limit.

Comment: What's the purpose of opening all the files at once? anyway user is going to look at only one fine at a time right? Why not open one by one?

Comment: Thank you, I really i'll throw this on the user responsibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article may help answering your question:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

These are extreme numbers that might not be practical in your case. You would have to use judgement or alternatively simply experiment and then set a conservative limit of a fifth of what you can handle on an average computer.